# Difference between UniqueConstraint vs unique_together - Django 2.2?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, python-3.6, django-managers

I started the new project in Django using version `2.2`,which has new constraint [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint), Does this same as [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) or it has any other differences?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: @DanielRoseman  got it thanks, when i search about unique_together i forgot to mention version 2.2 in url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty obvious from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>
> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together.
>   unique_together may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: when i search about unique_together i forgot to mention version 2.2 in url., thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`UniqueConstraint` has useful `condition`.

Just a little example. Let's say you want to check uniqueness for only active products.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['category_name', 'name'], 
                                    condition=models.Q(is_active=True),
                                    name='category_and_name_uniq')
        ]
```